# KeyRing for private GPG-Keys with "mattosaurus/PgpCore"

Tags: c#, cryptography, keystore, gnupg

can someone tell me how to create a private key ring for GPG keys with the "mattosaurus/PgpCore" library and then add existing keys?

Many thanks for your help